# Calculation results in NaN

Tags: c#

I was trying to calculate the result of a second degree equation using C#, but i get the result `NaN`. Can someone check my code to locate the error ?

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace desafio2_2
 {
  class Program
   {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
     Console.WriteLine("Please insert the values that multiply x², x and the independent term respectively: ");
     float a = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
     float b = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
     float c = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

     double bhaskarap1 = (Math.Pow(b, 2)) + (- 4 * a * c);
     double raiz1 = (-b + Math.Sqrt(bhaskarap1)) / (2 * a);
     double raiz2= (-b - Math.Sqrt(bhaskarap1)) / (2 * a);
        Console.WriteLine(raiz1);
        Console.WriteLine(raiz2);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: can we see the exact numbers you've entered for variable "a","b" and "c"?

Comment: [You need to learn how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), just asking people to find a problem for you is a horrible way to try and learn programming.

Answer (score 3):

It may be possible that the quadratic equation has no real roots. In this case the discriminant will be negative.

`Math.Sqrt(x)` returns NaN when when `x` is negative. You should test the discriminant for negative number before you call the square root function.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please insert the values that multiply x², x and the independent term respectively: ");
    float a = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    float b = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    float c = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    double bhaskarap1 = (Math.Pow(b, 2)) + (- 4 * a * c);
    if (bhaskarap1 < 0)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("There are no real solutions.");
         return;
    }
    double raiz1 = (-b + Math.Sqrt(bhaskarap1)) / (2 * a);
    double raiz2= (-b - Math.Sqrt(bhaskarap1)) / (2 * a);
    Console.WriteLine(raiz1);
    Console.WriteLine(raiz2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I was really stuck trying to fix the code.

Answer (score 1):

argument of sqrt method must be positive.

Answer (score 0):

The roots of the second degree equations are *complex* numbers in general case, e.g.

```
x**2 + 1 = 0
```

That's why I suggest using `Complex`, not `float`:

```
...
using System.Numerics;
...

// float.Parse - if you want to allow just real coefficients
Complex a = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Complex b = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Complex c = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Complex bhaskarap1 = b * b - 4 * a * c;
Complex raiz1 = (-b + Complex.Sqrt(bhaskarap1)) / (2 * a);
Complex raiz2 = (-b - Complex.Sqrt(bhaskarap1)) / (2 * a);
Console.WriteLine(raiz1);
Console.WriteLine(raiz2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check for NaN using a ternary operator like I did below to handle the case of a negative value for sqrt.

```
float a = 4.0f, b = 7.0f, c = -3.0f;

double my_var = ((Math.Pow(b, 2)) + (-4 * a * c));
Console.WriteLine(my_var);
Console.WriteLine(((-b + Math.Sqrt(-1 * my_var)) / (2 * a)));

double temp = (-b + Math.Sqrt(my_var)) / (2 * a); 
double raiz1 = temp.CompareTo(Double.NaN) < 1 ? 0.00 : temp;
temp = (-b + Math.Sqrt(-1 * my_var)) / (2 * a);
double raiz2 = temp.CompareTo(Double.NaN) < 1 ? 0.00 : temp;

Console.WriteLine($"Raiz1: {raiz1}\tRaiz2: {raiz2}");
```

Output:

```
97                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
NaN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Raiz1: 0.356107225224513        Raiz2: 0
```